# SSIS Bulk Insert Task from Format File

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I'd like to use the Bulk Insert Task using a format file to a target Server/Database/Table.  The table may or may not already exist.  Is there anyway to have the Bulk Insert Task in SSIS 2008 drop and re-create the table from my SSIS Format File as part of the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not put a task (SQL Task) in front of the Bulk Insert task that checks for the existence of the table, and if it doesn't exist, create it?

Comment: Beat me to it!-that is exactly what you would have to do.

Comment: The problem is I'm generating the SSIS Format File dynamically based on input from an Excel Spreadsheet.  That means the target table structure can vary.

Comment: Since I failed to mention the need for a dynamic table structure I will accept this answer to the benefit of future people who may ask the question.